# C# How to disable button when the value is zero

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm a beginner to C# programming and I really need some help :)

I made 2 buttons that will increment or decrement the value in the text box which is initially zero.

```
       private void bminus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NUMBER--;
        textBox2.Text = NUMBER.ToString();
    }

    private void bplus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NUMBER++;
        textBox2.Text = NUMBER.ToString();
    }
```

Will there be a way that the decrement button will be disabled if the value is 0 so that there won't be negative numbers? Thank you, I'd really appreciate anyone's help! :)

Comment: The answer will depend on what platform you are using. You might want to tag the question with winforms or asp.net or wpf, etc..

Answer (score 3):

```
private void bminus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NUMBER--;
    textBox2.Text = NUMBER.ToString();
    if(NUMBER == 0){
        bminus.Enabled = false;
    }
}

private void bplus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NUMBER++;
    textBox2.Text = NUMBER.ToString();
    bminus.Enabled = true;
}
```

That should do.

Answer (score 1):

You can just directly insert logical state `NUMBER` not being 0 to your `textBox2` `Enabled` property:

```cs
textBox2.Enabled = NUMBER != 0;
```

Or make a separate function from this:

```cs
private bool IsNotZero(double n)
{
    return n != 0;
}
```

then:

```cs
textBox2.Enabled = IsNotZero(NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add the following to the `textBox2.TextChanged` event handler and it should work with your current code.

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int output;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out output))
    {
        bminus.Enabled = int.Parse(textBox2.Text) > 0;
    }
}
```

***NOTE:*** No one here has specified checking for an integer so I added `int.TryParse` and `int.Parse` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Button have a property named Enabled which you can set to true or false based on your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value using if condition. If the value is null or zero you can use button.enabled = false; code.`if(value == zero || value == null) { button.enabled=false;} else {button.enabled = true;}`